# moving one specific div

Tags: properties, html

so here's the situation:

i have 2 divs one on top of another.  i defined them one after the other and used the margin-top property of the second div so it would overlap the first.

what i need to do is set the first div to be offscreen until a certain point.  but anything i've tried so far (plain javascript or jquery functions) seem to change whatever property i'm using for *all* the divs in my file rather than just the one in question.

is there any way to just change properties of one specific div without changing them all?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

yes, specify the DIV by ID

```
<div id='div1'>hi</div>
<div id='div2'>bye</div>
<span id='show2'>show2</span>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#div2').hide();

  $('#show2').click(function(){
    $('#div2').show();
  });
});

</script>
```

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aCDQm/1/) for example

Comment: i did try using an id to reference the div...but when i modify a specific css property with jquery (margin-top in this case) it modifies it for all divs, even though i specified one by id. also, just using the show/hide function won't work; i need to set the div to live somewhere offscreen until a later point when i'll move it back. any ideas? thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

Apply an id to the div like

```
<div id="first">...</div>
<div id="second">...</div>
```

Select the div with jquery $("#first")...

Comment: i did try using an id to reference the div...but when i modify a specific css property with jquery (margin-top in this case) it modifies it for all divs, even though i specified one by id. also, just using the show/hide function won't work; i need to set the div to live somewhere offscreen until a later point when i'll move it back. any ideas? thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

How about giving that div an ID?

```
<div id="specificDiv">
   <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

..and then you call it as follows,

```
$('#specificDiv') //assuming you're using jQuery..
```

Comment: i did try using an id to reference the div...but when i modify a specific css property with jquery (margin-top in this case) it modifies it for all divs, even though i specified one by id.   

also, just using the show/hide function won't work; i need to set the div to live somewhere offscreen until a later point when i'll move it back.  

any ideas?  thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Hey Ryan, could you show some markup and the relative javascript code? Are you trying to achieve some sort of an animation effect?

Comment: yeah, i'm using jquery to fade in a background image in a div.  i've got another div on top of that with a flash file in it.  the problem is the buttons in the flash won't function while the div below is animating (or while it's hidden; no idea why), so i'm just trying to move the lower div offscreen until it's needed, because for some reason that makes the buttons work.

so really i just need a code to set the position of the lower div offscreen, then i can set it back.  or animate it or whatever - as long as it's offscreen.  

not sure what code to post that would be relevant, though.